# Logfile not generated using Cordova file plugin in Android Nougat & Marshmallow

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the Cordova File Plugin to create a logfile in my internal storage of my device which is running Nougat. I do not have an external SD card.

Here is my code

```
function myLogger(logString) {
    alert("Inside mylogger");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        alert("Inside Local File System");
        var absPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
        var fileDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, '');
        var fileName = "logfile.txt";
        var filePath = fileDir + fileName;
        alert(filePath);
        fs.root.getFile(filePath, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
            alert("Inside getFile method");
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                alert("Inside createwriter method");
                fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); // Start write position at EOF.
                var logStringWithTimeStamp = Date.parse(new Date()) + " : " + logString + "\n";
                var blob = new Blob([logStringWithTimeStamp], {type: 'text/plain', endings: 'native'});
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Err logString" + err);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Err" + err);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err1" + err);
    });
}

myLogger("Hello Logger");
```

In this code I am getting Error Code 9 - INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR

I have checked repeated times - the code is not entering fs.root.getFile block. So I changed the code a bit.

ALTERNATIVE CODE which gives no error but still logfile is not generated

```
function myLogger(logString) {
    alert("Inside mylogger");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        alert("Inside Local File System");
        var absPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
        var fileDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, '');
        var fileName = "logfile.txt";
        var filePath = fileDir + fileName;
        alert(filePath);
        fs.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
            alert("Inside getFile method");
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                alert("Inside createwriter method");
                fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); // Start write position at EOF.
                var logStringWithTimeStamp = Date.parse(new Date()) + " : " + logString + "\n";
                var blob = new Blob([logStringWithTimeStamp], {type: 'text/plain', endings: 'native'});
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Err logString" + err);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Err" + err);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err1" + err);
    });
}

myLogger("Hello Logger");
```

In the 2nd Code I am giving fileName as parameter instead of filePath in the getFile method. Here I am not getting any error but still logfile is not generated. I have all permissions in Android Manifest. I have also given storage access to my Ionic Cordova app. Why am I unable to generate logfile in my device internal storage?

Edit 1 : I have also tested in Marshmallow. In the 2nd code it is going to all blocks, there are no error but still logfile is not created

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can see with your implementation is this line:

```
var fileDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, '');
```

This is replacing the absolute path and making it relative. You are then using this to construct your `filePath` and passing this to `fs.root.getFile` which expects an absolute path, not a relative one.

I would do it slightly differently from your approach and resolve the directory in which you want to create the file then use that directory entry to create the local file entry, something like this:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    myLogger("Hello Logger");
}

function myLogger(logString) {
    var fileDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
    var fileName = "logfile.txt";
    var filePath = fileDir + fileName;
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileDir, function (dirEntry) {
        log("Inside Local File System");

        log("Write to: " + filePath);
        dirEntry.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
            log("Inside getFile method");
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                log("Inside createwriter method");

                fileWriter.onwriteend = function () {
                    log("Successfully wrote file");
                };
                fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                    error("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
                };

                fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); // Start write position at EOF.
                var logStringWithTimeStamp = Date.parse(new Date()) + " : " + logString + "\n";
                var blob = new Blob([logStringWithTimeStamp], {type: 'text/plain', endings: 'native'});
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, function (err) {
                error("creating file writer " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        }, function (err) {
            error("getting file for writing " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }, function (err) {
        error("requesting filesystem " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}

function error(msg){
    log("ERROR: "+msg);
}

function log(msg){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>'+msg+'</p>';
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```